# How to specify an MDB destination name in ejb-jar.xml for JBoss

Tags: jboss, ejb, ejb-jar.xml

I am trying to configure an EJB 2.1 MDB in ejb-jar.xml.
My problem is there is no clear way to specify the destination (Queue name) the MDB suppose to listen to. I have exhausted the web without finding any useful information.

So in my ejb-jar.xml I have configured my DMB like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">
<ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>   
        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>LoginListenerMDB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.mydomain.LoginListener</ejb-class>               
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>                          
            <message-driven-destination>            
                <destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</destination-type>                            
            </message-driven-destination>                   
        </message-driven>
...
```

How can I specify the Queue name or jndi name the MDB should be listening to?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. It is actually defined in another config file (eeeegrr) called jboss.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss PUBLIC
    "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS 6.0//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss_6_0.dtd">
<jboss>
    <enterprise-beans>

        <message-driven>
           <ejb-name>LoginListenerMDB</ejb-name>
           <destination-jndi-name>queue/LoginQueue</destination-jndi-name>         
        </message-driven>
...
```

I don't why it was done this way? Is that to allow binding the same MDB to more than one destination?

Comment: I tried, doesn't work. It seems that the config file wasn't used at all.